# Is it possible to add background color in each cell in FullCalendar V5 timeGridWeek?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have this Time Grid Week from FullCalendar

[Time Grid Week from FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atba5.png)

Is it possible to change the background color for a specific day and specific time? For example in Monday from 7:00AM to 10:00AM, I want to change the background color in red.

I tried to inspect the element, I can't find any element that represents a single cell, but I can only see a full row.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpDD4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Simply create a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)